# drop down spinner in android not dialog spinner

Tags: android, android-spinner

I want to have a drop down spinner in my app, but when I tapped on spinner, spinner open a dialog and show the items in that in fact I want to have a spinner like this image:

[image]

but, my spinner is like this

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below code : - Where mMyArray is array of String to be displayed. mAcitvity is context .

`Spinner  mMySpinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.myValues);`

`ArrayAdapter<String> mMyadapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(mActivity,`
                `android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, mMyArray);`
 `mMyadapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);`

`mMySpinner.setAdapter(mMyadapter)`

Let me know if it works

Comment: are you using the theme `android:Theme.Holo.Light`

Comment: yes, this is my styles.xml code:                                     "<resources>
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light"/>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme"/>
</resources>"